# Mage::log is not performing as expected

Tags: magento-1.9, log, 404

I have extended Mage_Cms_IndexController so that I can log my 404 pages. Within that class I have...

```
public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
    //Begin Modification
    Mage::log('My log data', null, '404s.log');
   //End modification
    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_NO_ROUTE_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
}
```

System logs are enabled and /var as well as /var/log are chmod to 777.

Comment: Are you sure that your controller rewrite is enabled and it's class rewrites Mage_Cms_IndexController?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forceLog = true?

```
Mage::log('My log data', null, '404s.log', true);
```

Comment: If i run my observer https://paste.ofcode.org/37ccujDxcru9uDgYkE2PMiy   my log file name 35 instead of event.log, may i know what is the issue? screenshot -> https://snipboard.io/62r8hA.jpg @Luke Rodgers  thanks